# Mars longitude reference?

Tags: coordinate-systems, conventions, planets, celestial-mechanics

Platforms like NASA's JPL HORIZONS web-interface for solar system dynamics often have obtainable parameters like sub-solar or sub-terrestrial longitude for a given time and celestial object. (example: Mars)

Where is this longitude measured from? Is there a widely accepted standard?

Comment: Would [space.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mars's prime meridian was set in 1972 as the center line of the crater Airy-0, which is at S5.1 E0.0.

(https://mars.jpl.nasa.gov/mgs/msss/camera/images/01_31_01_releases/airy0/)

Comment: A reference would be nice. Even the Moon has two competing body-fixed reference frames, both widely used.